# Как задать значение по умолчанию для нового мета-поля в wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, metadata, метаданные

Есть сайт на `wordpress` с большим количеством объявлений (тип записи, созданный темой). Я добавил для объявлений новое произвольное мета-поле `cp_wholespare`, которое имеет только 2 значения (Запчасть|автомобиль целиком), которое при редактировании выбирается радиокнопкой. Проблема в том, что в теле объявления хоть и выбрано активным первое из имеющихся значений по умолчанию (запчасть), но в базе данных оно не прописано и соответственно при фильтрации по этому полю не ищет.

Если устанавливать переключатель вручную, то в поиске по мета-полю в таблице находит значения согласно структуры

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta`

meta_id  post_id  meta_key       meta_value
459584   20025    cp_wholespare  автомобиль целиком
459621   20018    cp_wholespare  Запчасть
```

Вопрос: как задать значение по умолчанию для этого поля сразу для всех объявлений?

Все объявления у меня получилось выбрать вот так:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'ad_listing'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'cp_category'
```

А как теперь всем присвоить мета-поле 'cp_wholespare' со значением 'Запчасть'?
Так?

```
UPDATE *
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'ad_listing'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'cp_category'
ON wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'cp_wholespare'
SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'Запчасть'
```

Comment: Это какой-то неправильный путь. Ну, обновите вы через mysql все, что есть. А завтра новое объявление будет создано. Опять править базу? Надо при сохранении объявления проверять метаполе,и если оно пустое, записывать в него значение по умолчанию. Ну, или при выборке использовать NOT_EXISTS

Comment: @KAGG Design я проверял - для новых объявлений, которые уже созданы после этого мета-поля, значение по умолчанию устанавливается автоматом. Проблема только со старыми объявлениями - вы можете подсказать, как сделать корректный запрос - правильно ли я мыслю или есть ошибка?

Comment: Вроде похоже на правильный запрос, но мне кажется, такой запрос присвоит всем полям значение "Запчасть". А надо только пустым.

Comment: @KAGG Design ругается на `UPDATE *` (ожидалось выражение и неожиданный токен (около *)) и на `ON wp_postmeta.meta_key = `cp_wholespare` (неожиданный токен около )

Comment: А при таком расладе ругается на повтор wp_postmeta           `UPDATE wp_postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'ad_listing'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'cp_category'
SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'Запчасть'
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'cp_wholespare'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Более правильно в даном случае использывть средства WP, тем более функцию добавления поля можно выполнить в будущем. Принцип:

Выбриаем нужные посты с БД запросом

```
$args = [
'post_type' => 'ad_listing',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => [
   'key' => 'cp_category',
   'compare' => 'EXIST'
   ]
];
```

Далее запускаем цикл проверки метаключа на существование и обновляем его если есть, если нету то добавляем. Запускаем нашу функцию один раз с темой например(вставляем код ниже в functions.php темы и раз обновляем страницу, потом код можно убрать):

```
 function custom_upd_meta(){
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'ad_listing',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => [
            'key' => 'cp_category',
            'compare' => 'EXIST'
        ]
    ];
    $post_list = new WP_Query($args);
    if($post_list->have_posts()) : while ($post_list->have_posts()) : $post_list->the_post();
        $id = get_the_ID();
        if(get_post_meta($id,'cp_wholespare',true)==false) :
            add_post_meta($id,'cp_wholespare', 'Запчасть');
        endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
}
add_action('update_my_meta','custom_upd_meta');
do_action('update_my_meta');
```

Код добавит ключ к посту если он не существует, если нужно обновить, то вместо `add_post_meta` просто используйте `update_post_meta`

Answer (score 3):

Нашел этот пост на первых позициях по запросу "wp мета поле по умолчанию". Поэтому решил добавить ответ в соответствии.

```php
add_action( 'save_post_post_type', 'set_default_meta', 10, 3 );

function set_default_meta( $post_ID ) {

    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'meta_value', true );

    if ( $meta_value == '' && !wp_is_post_revision( $post_ID ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'meta_value', 0, true );
    }
}
```